# Can anybody explain what exactily is happening in this SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT sal 
FROM emp e 
WHERE 5 >= (SELECT COUNT(sal) 
            FROM emp a 
            WHERE a.sal <= e.sal)
ORDER BY sal;
```

I know that we are going to get least five earners. But how exactly does the query execute? I am unable to understand. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

This query has what's called a *correlated subquery*. You can think of the query as running two nested loops, iterating over all possible pairs of rows from `emp`. Here is the heart of it:

```
WHERE a.sal <= e.sal
```

`e` designates the row from the *outer* `SELECT` (`FROM emp e`), while `a` designates the row from the *nested* `SELECT` (`FROM emp a`). The condition makes the nested query count all `emp` rows with salaries less than the one of the outer query. The outer query includes the salary when the count of lower salaries is less than or equal to five.

Note that rows with identical salaries will be counted multiple times, potentially reducing the number of rows in the return set. For example, if there are six bottom earners with an identical salary, the query will return an empty set of rows. You can use `DISTINCT` to change this behavior you can.

Comment: thanks for u r answer. But i don't understand the sentence " The outer query includes the salary when the count of lower salaries is less than or equal to five.". But in outer query we are using 5>=. In the inner query i am counting sal whenever a.sal<=e.sal means i am always getting higher salaries only. so how can outer query includes sal when the count of lower salaries is less than or equal to five. in fact it should give higher salaries. I am not able to understand i am thinking in wrong direction please correct me

Answer (score 0):

Its always help full to see the execution plan to see how the query will be executed please go through the image for understanding how the query will run

[image]

you can go through the below link for finding more about sql query execution plans

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1856/sql-server-query-execution-plans-in-sql-server-management-studio/