# Can you explain what this SQL query does?

Tags: sql

```
Select sal
from emp e 
where 3 >= (select count (sal) 
            from emp a
            where a.sal <= e.sal)
order by sal;
```

It will return lowest three salary in Emp Table in Ascending order

Example : `Emp` table

```
Sal (Column/Attribute)
50
40
10
20
30
```

Result :

```
10
20
30
```

Somebody gave the above answer. But while comparing I am getting top3 salaries. Where exactly am I going wrong? I don't understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anybody explain what exactily is happening in this SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826699/can-anybody-explain-what-exactily-is-happening-in-this-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count (sal) from emp a where a.sal<=e.sal
```

This return to you count of rows that have salaty greater than `e.sal` from upper level select; For example, for lowest `sel` it will return number of all rows;

```
 where 3>= (...)
```

This return to you row, that have only `3` row with greater `sal` than given.

```
order by sal
```

This only make on order by `sal`

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

If your data set (e.sal) consists of (50, 40, 10, 20, 30), then walking through your data on:

```
where 3 >=
   (select count (sal) 
    from emp a
    where a.sal <= e.sal)
```

Your results:

```
For e.sal = 50: Count = 5 [50, 40, 10, 20, 30] FALSE
For e.sal = 40: Count = 4 [40, 10, 20, 30] FALSE
For e.sal = 10: Count = 1 [10] TRUE
For e.Sal = 20: Count = 2 [10, 20] TRUE
For e.Sal = 30: Count = 3 [10, 20 30] TRUE
```

So, your WHERE clause limits you to 10, 20, 30, which you then put in ascending order: 10, 20, 30

Comment: Thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

That query does indeed return the lowest three salaries (although there is a better way to do that).  I'm not sure how you're getting the top 3 salaries.

For each row in the `emp` table, the subquery in the `WHERE` clause is returning the number of salaries that are less than or equal to the current salary.  The results are like this:

```
+-----+-------------------------+
| sal |       # of sal <=       |
+-----+-------------------------+
|  10 | 1  (10)                 |
|  20 | 2  (10, 20)             |
|  30 | 3  (10, 20, 30)         |
|  40 | 4  (10, 20, 30, 40)     |
|  50 | 5  (10, 20, 30, 40, 50) |
+-----+-------------------------+
```

Now look at those results and find the rows where 3 >= the `"# of sal <="`, and you'll see that it's the first 3 rows (10, 20, and 30).

Are you sure you didn't accidentally mix up a `<` and a `>`?

Comment: Thank u very much